# jQuery dynamic underlining

Tags: jquery, class, toggle, hidden, underline

I've got hidden divs that my navigation menu shows/hides. When showing/hiding the divs, the corresponding menu option is underlined; meaning the former div fades out, the current div fades in, and the underline follows. The underline does not hide when you close a div by re-clicking on its name in the menu.

So ideally the underline will dynamically be added/removed following the dynamic div toggling.

Thanks for your time and patience!

HTML:

```
    <div id="nav">
        <a class="home" id="show_brand" title="THE BRAND">THE BRAND</a><br />
        <a class="home" id="show_campaigns" title="CAMPAIGNS">CAMPAIGNS</a><br />
        <a id="collection" title="COLLECTION">COLLECTION</a><br />
        <a class="home" id="show_inquiries" title="INQUIRIES">INQUIRIES</a>
    </div>
    <div class="current" id="brand">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <p>this is content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="campaigns">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <p>this is content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="inquiries">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <p>this is content</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    width:165px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:10px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:FuturaStdLightCondensed;
    line-height:120%;
}
.close {
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:4;
    background:url(../images/close.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#brand {
    width:300px;
    height:188px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-94px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    position:absolute;
}
#campaigns {
    width:160px;
    height:68px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-34px;
    margin-left:-80px;
    position:absolute;
}
#campaigns a {
    color:#fff;
}
#inquiries {
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-250px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#brand, #campaigns, #inquiries').hide();
$('.home').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("show_","").toLowerCase();
    var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
    console.log(id);
    if ($('.current').length === 0) {
        showContent($content)
    }
    else {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function() {
            showContent($content)
        });
    }
    $('.home').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
});
function showContent(content) {
    content.fadeIn(600);
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    content.addClass('current');
}
$('.close').click(function() {
    $('.current').fadeOut(600);
    $('.home').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#about, #campaigns, #inquiries').hide();
$('.home').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
    if ($('.current').length === 0) {
        showContent($content)
    }
    else {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function() {
            showContent($content)
        });
    }
    $('.home').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');  

});
function showContent(content) {
    content.fadeIn(600);
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    content.addClass('current');
}
$('.close').click(function() {
    $('.current').fadeOut(600);
    $('.home').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

Comment: @yoda Underlines the appropriate menu item when clicked andhides when one of the other options is clicked. does not go away when clicking on the .close class or when closing the div by clicking it's name.

Comment: Don't expect people to do the job for you. The tip is there, you should know what to do now :)

Comment: @yoda
I hear you, Yoda. Just trying to help out a friend and it's simply knowledge I don't have. I tried dropping in $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline'); to the .close click function, but with no avail. Anyway, I don't mean to waste your time or be greedy. The whole site is about community and helping eachother.

Comment: @yoda: The code is the same as my updated question code with the exception of console.log(id); above the if statement. This toggles the underline when closing the div from the .close button, but doesn't toggle it when clicking on the original .home link

Comment: @Daniel Redwood: can you paste some CSS (the required one only) so that I can test on jsfiddle?