# jQuery toggling hidden div issue with multiple word names

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html, toggle, anchor

I have a function that toggles hidden divs and works beautifully at it. unfortunately, the "brand" section just got changed to "the brand." the code was graciously improved and written dynamically by one of you geniuses and uses the anchor's content name to select the div to show/hide. unfortunately i need THE (space) BRAND. No bueno!

Ideas? Thank you!

p.s. this function works if you take THE out of the "show_brand" anchor.

HTML:

```
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav_left">
            <a class="home" id="show_brand" title="BRAND">THE BRAND</a><br />
            <a class="home" id="show_campaigns" title="CAMPAIGNS">CAMPAIGNS</a><br />
            <a href="collection/" title="COLLECTION">COLLECTION</a><br />
            <a class="home" id="show_inquiries" title="INQUIRIES">INQUIRIES</a>
        </div>
        <div id="campaigns">
            <a href="campaigns/neo_balletto/" title="NEO BALLETTO">NEO BALLETTO</a><br />
            <a href="campaigns/poetic_deco/" title="POETIC DECO">POETIC DECO</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="current" id="brand">
        <p>content</p> 
    </div>
    <div id="inquiries">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#brand, #campaigns, #inquiries').hide();
$('.home').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
    if ($('.current').length === 0) {
        showContent($content)
    }
    else {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function() {
            showContent($content)
        });
    }
    $('.home').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
});
function showContent(content) {
    content.fadeIn(600);
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    content.addClass('current');
}
$('.close').click(function() {
    $('.current').fadeOut(600);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just change

`var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();`

to

`var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("show_","").toLowerCase();`

And your code will work ,no matter what the content of the div is

Check http://jsfiddle.net/3AnZw/1/ for a demo

Comment: Nailed it. I'm having an issue with the underline toggling. It switches to the other menu items when clicking on one to another, but doesn't go away when clicking on the .close class or the name of the active div. Ideas? the question is posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149609/navigation-toggle-underline-while-subsequently-showing-and-hiding-divs-with-jquer

Comment: Well I did read the question ,but couldn't really understand your requirement

Comment: Ah, i thought i had updated the question last night and I really hadn't. Just made the question more specific and clear. If you've got the time, I'd love your insight. You seem to have a clear understanding- something I do not!

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of:

1) Use the title attribute to navigate to the DIV's and toggle the visibility. i.e:

```
$('#brand, #campaigns, #inquiries').hide();
$('.home').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("title").toLowerCase(); // note the change from html to attr("title")
    var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
    if ($('.current').length === 0) {
        showContent($content)
    }
    else {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function() {
            showContent($content)
        });
    }
    $('.home').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
});
function showContent(content) {
    content.fadeIn(600);
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    content.addClass('current');
}
$('.close').click(function() {
    $('.current').fadeOut(600);
});
```

2) Change the id of div from brand to the_brand and use the JS below:

```
$('#brand, #campaigns, #inquiries').hide();
$('.home').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_"); //Replace spaces with _ got ID
    var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
    if ($('.current').length === 0) {
        showContent($content)
    }
    else {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function() {
            showContent($content)
        });
    }
    $('.home').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
});
function showContent(content) {
    content.fadeIn(600);
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    content.addClass('current');
}
$('.close').click(function() {
    $('.current').fadeOut(600);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can update the id brand to "the_brand", then you can just add

```
var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_');
```

That is, replace spaces with underscores in the ID to select it.  If that's not an option and you just want to always use the last word, do this:

```
var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase().replace(/.* /, '');
```

This regex will replace everything up to the last space leaving the last word (tested with THE THE BRAND)

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
var $content = $('div[id="' + id + '"]:not(:visible)');
```